# Create data model according to Select Case Instruction

Tags: sql, database, vba, excel

this question might appear a bit strange to you but i´ll try to explain it.
In our company in the production department we are tracking machine data. This data is also used for evaluating the quality of the production process. 
In the following i will refer to these attributes:

- productId
- componentOfProduct -> the component which is affected by the error
- routeStepOfError
- causeOfError

The problem is, that the data the machine produces is not in the order the management wants to have it for evaluation. 
So we have to do a data matching. Most of the time it is a simple relationship e.g. matching several productId numbers to 1 product Name / Group.
But in the case of the routeStepOfError it´s different. For some cases the routeStep the production lines are logging can be matched to the routeStep for the management reports like descirbed above with the productIds.
But for some routeSteps a way more complicated matching is done. So far it´s implementet in an VBA app which is matching the database output and writes data into a spreadsheet. the matching is done via Select Case Instructions like this:

```
Select Case routeStep
  Case EOL
    Select Case productId
       Case 1111, 1112, 1113
          Select Case causeOfError
             Case A1:   
                 Select Case componentOfProduct
                    Case "be1": routeStepReport = "final optical test"
                    Case Else: routeStepReport = "end of line"
                 End Select   
             Case Else: routeStepReport = "end of line"
          End Select
       Case Else: routeStepReport = "end of line"
    End Select
  Case...
End Select
```

...i know that the syntax might not be correct, but i hope you get what i´m trying to say: sometimes the mathing from routeStep to routeStepReport (i.e. the value we need for our management reports) depends on the `routeStep`, the `productId`, the `componentOfProduct` and the `causeOfError`. 
...and these `Select Case` Statements are really long as there are many products and many routeSteps in our production process. So, each time, there is a change in the production programm / process, this has to be maintained in the VBA Code which is far away from being perfect as only 1 guy in our company really knows where in the code to look for this and how to maintain it.

So, i proposed to implement the whole matching in an SQL Database and just create the right relationships between the values of the machines and the values the management wants to have. Togehter with an interface in php or whatever people could just do the matching quite easily. 
Well, for the simple matchings like productIds to Product Groups this works quite fine, but for the routeSteps like described above for me this might be a problem. 
I would have created one table with the following attributes:

|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|

|routeSTepofError |productId        | componentOfProd | causeOfError    | routeStepReport |

|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|

But Let´s say, we have about 20 routeSteps, 50 productIds, each with about 4 Components and 10 causes of error this table might be endless as well and really hard to maintain.

Maybe i should have told before, that for the majority of routeSTepofErrors, there is a simple matiching from routeSTepofError to routeStepReport regardless to productIds, components and causes.... but if some mathings are depending on all 4 criterias, i have to completly fill the table above, don´t I?

Maybe there´s an easier solution to achieve this, but yet I cannot see it.

So i would be really pleased for each and every hint you could give me for solving this problem (i cannot change the way of matching itself; they still want to have "their" well-known figures :-) ).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use two tables, tblRouteStepErrorMatch and tblRouteStepErrorException.

```
tblRouteStepErrorMatch
    routeStepofError
    routeStepReport
tblRouteStepErrorException
    routeStepError
    productID
    componentOfProd
    causeOfError
    routeStepReport
```

Then in your code, check the Exception table. If there's not match, go to the Match table.

```
ExcRecordset = SELECT * FROM tblRouteStepErrorException WHERE ...
If BOF(ExcRecordset) and EOF(ExcRecordset) Then 'No match in exception table
    MatchRecordset = SELECT * FROM tblRouteStepErrorMatch WHERE ... 'go get from match table
    get result from MatchRecordset
Else
    get result from ExcRecordset
End if
```

Now your exceptions are a lot easier to maintain because there are far fewer of them and the match table becomes the fallback for when a special case isn't found.

Comment: Now, after having implemented the solution i want to say thanks for the advice! I just had to do some modifications as the matching had to be done for many data fields, each with their own matching tables. so, i decided to work with some temporary tables for handing data over to other procedures. Thanks a lot!